# Optional non capturing regex groups do always capture

Tags: regex

Somehow optional capturing groups are not working for me. I am trying to capture text from a string which sometimes containing unwanted text.

```
I want this, N3
and this
this 2
this 2, N1
```

This is unwanted

> , N3
>   , N1

My regex looks like this:

```
^[a-z0-9 ]*(?:, N\d)?$
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/la3G2Q/2

How can I retrieve the text before the comma even if there is sometimes the comma?

```
I want this
and this
this 2
this 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a non-capturing group, you can use a lookahead to assert that the characters you want are followed by either `, N` and a digit or the end-of-line:

```
^[a-z0-9 ]+(?=, N\d$|$)
```

This way the characters from the `,` will not be included in the match.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/la3G2Q/3)

Alternatively, you can add a capture group around the characters you want, and then just use group 1 as your match:

```
^([a-z0-9 ]+)(?:, N\d)?$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/la3G2Q/4)

Comment: Great, thank you! One question, I noticed the plus sign. What is the difference between plus and star?

Comment: @merlin `+` means 1 or more, `*` 0 or more. That was a typo when I was editing the regex, it doesn't need to be `+`.

Comment: Perfect, in that case + is better.